# Вредны ли глобальные переменные?

Tags: php

Влияет ли данный вариант как-то на уменьшение скорости загрузки например? Избегать ли глобальных переменных?

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 5");
$d = mysql_fetch_array($q);
$id = $d['id'];

function check() {
 global $id;
 return $id;
}
```

Comment: так они не скоростью вредны, а тем что в любой незащищенный запрос может вклиниться кто угодно и как угодно, вплоть до форматирования ос, тем не менее тот же вордпресс использует гл. переменные и ничего, в общем это личное дело каждого что делать с гл. переменными, но по моему они не рекомендуются уже.

Comment: @Maris: хотел бы добавить, что этому "уже" лет наверное втрое больше, чем мне.

Comment: ИМО, жечь на костре всех кто использует global в своём коде.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Избегать ли глобальных переменных?

Это зависит конкретно от того "как программируешь". 
Если программируешь на ООП, то глобальные переменные в ООП - это **АНТИ-ПАТТЕРН**.

Глобальные переменны плохи тем, что они скрывают зависимости, когда они должны быть столь очевидными. Если ты слышал, что такое **тестирование кода** PHPUnit'om, так вот - глобальное состояние делает код не тестируемым (а следовательно - не качественным ).

Хорошо написанные системы, передают переменные в качестве параметров, вот так

```
$stuff = array('foo' => 'bar');

function test(array $stuff){
  print_r($stuff);
}
```

А не вот так:

```
function test() {
  global $stuff;
  print_r($stuff);
}
```

Полное описание и обьяснение не уместится в один вопрос. Поэтому кратко подведем итоги:

- В ООП следует избегать глобальных состояних
- Используемые переменные, следует передавать как аргумент
- Глобальность скрывает зависимости (одного класса от другого итп)

Отвечая на твой вопрос: **Да старатся избегать. Всегда**

Comment: Я вот заметил что в каждом твоем ответе присутствует 

>**АНТИ-ПАТТЕРН**.

Это твоя фишка? Которая просто вставляется в каждый ответ или что? Есть много других слов.

Если так прочитать примерно половину твоих ответов, так php,mysql любые фреймворки - это **АНТИ-ПАТТЕРН**. Ты реально понимаешь значение этого или просто любишь писать жирным именно это?

Comment: все же несмотря на такую странную любовь к этому замечательному слову, парень прав - глобальные переменные штука плохая

Comment: @Shrek & @DreamChild, я никогда в жизни не читал книг на русском языке по программированию и по паттернам. Паттерн - означает шаблон, образец, но называть это = Анти-Шаблон или Анти-образец - у меня язык не поворачивается. Любая литература по **ООП**, описывает ТО ЧЕГО ДЕЛАТЬ НЕ НУЖНО - как АНТИ-ПАТТЕРН. @Shrek, когда я пишу жирным я хочу это слово **отчетливо выделить** уделяя особое внимание на него.

Comment: Ты все равно не понял сути того что я написал :)

Comment: @Shrek Ты это загнул - **Если так прочитать примерно половину твоих ответов, так php,mysql любые фреймворки - это АНТИ-ПАТТЕРН**

Зайди в мой профиль, прогуляйся по ответам - такого нигде нет. Про фрэйиворки я где-то писал что YII - это "..цензура..". Да да, про паттерны и анти, я в частности всегда упоминаю, посколько просто не думание о них во время написания кода - причиняет мне боль. И уже никак без этого.